# How to do fix a relative import issue: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.assets'; '__main__' is not a package`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to import data from another part of my project, but the import statement doesn't seem to work.

The way my code is structured is like this:

```py
from .foo.bar import x, y ,z


class abc:
    # stuff putting x, y, and z into a db
```

The directory is structured like this:

```
-project
    -foo
        -bar
            -x.py
            -y.py
            -z.py
    -bin
        -script.py
```

The expected result is that the data should be imported without issue, but when run, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.assets'; '__main__' is not a package` error.

Comment: You need to add an `__init__.py` to your folders to make them packages.

Comment: put an empty `__init__.py` in your `project` directory

Comment: Your example doesn't match the exception you show. What is the `assets` module you're *really* trying to import? Either show your real code, or show the real exception you get when you run your example code.